# Unable to Mock Glassfish Jersey Client response object

Tags: unit-testing, glassfish, mockito, jersey-client, jersey-2.0

I am having problems with creating a mock Response object to use with my unit tests. I am using `org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-client` version 2.3.1 to implement my RESTful client and `mockito` version 1.9.5 to help me with mock objects. Here is my test's code:

```
@Test
public void testGetAll() throws IOException {
    // Given
    String expectedResource = "expectedResource"

    final Response expectedRes =  Response.ok(expectedResource, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    String receivedResource;

    BDDMockito.given(this.client.getSimpleClient().getAllWithResponse()).willReturn(expectedRes);

    // When
    receivedResource = this.client.getAll();

    // Then
    Assert.assertNotNull("Request constructed correctly and response received.", receivedResource);
    Assert.assertEquals("Resource is equal to expected.", expectedResource, receivedResource);
}
```

The problem occurs when `this.client.getAll();` is executed. Here is that method's code:

```
public String getAll() throws GenericAragornException, ProcessingException{
    Response response = this.simpleClient.getAllWithResponse();

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        processErrorResponse(response);
    }

    String entity = response.readEntity(String.class);

    // No errors so return entity converted to resourceType.
    return entity;
}
```

Note that I am mocking the this.simpleClient.getAllWithResponse() method with the manually created Response. When it reaches the `response.readEntity(resourceListType);` instruction, Jersey throws the following exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException - Method not supported on an outbound message.`.  After lots of research and debugging, it turns that, for some reason, when I create a Response using the response builder such as `Response.ok(expectedResource, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();` it creates it as an OutboundResponse instead of as an **InboundResponse**. The latter are the only ones permitted to use the `Response.readEntity()` method. If it is an **OutboundResponse**, the exception is thrown.

However, I could not find any way of converting the manually created response to an InboundResponse. So my tests are doomed :(. Do you guys/gals have any idea of what I can do here? I don't want to mock the Response object with Mockito because I think it could be a code smell since it violates the Law of Demeter. Sincerely I am out of ideas here. Things like this should be simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this error because when you use the `ResponseBuilder`, it returns an `OutboundJaxrsResponse` message that can not be processed with `readEntity()`.

I noticed that I had this error only when I was calling the Jax-RS component directly. For exemple, if I have `DefaultController` annotated with `@Path("/default")` and if I tried to directly call its method, I could not use `readEntity()` and had the same error as you.

```
defaultController.get();
```

Now, when I was using the grizzly2 test provider and using a client to target the Rest Url (in the previous case, it is `/default`), the message I received in response was a ScopedJaxrsResponse. And then I could use the `readEntity()` method.

```
target("/default").request.get();
```

In your case, you mocked the simpleClient in order to reply with a response built with `ResponseBuilder` that is not processed by jersey. It's comparable to calling directly my `DefaultController` method.

Without mocking the `readEntity()` method, I suggest you to find a way to get your response processed by Jersey and turned into a `ScopedJaxrsResponse`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the input!! Just one question...if it were you... would you mock the readEntity() method?

Comment: It depends of what you want to test ?

Comment: That the getAll method does what it is supposed to do and returns what it is supposed to return depending on what it receives.

Answer (score 11):

You can also mock response with Mockito:

```
final Response response = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
Mockito.when(response.getStatus()).thenReturn(responseStatus);
Mockito.when(response.readEntity(Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
Mockito.when(response.readEntity(Mockito.any(GenericType.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

responseStatus is status code associated with the response and responseEnitty is of course entity you want to return. You can use that mock as a return statment in Mockito (e.g. ... thenReturn(response)).

In my projects I create builders for different types for mocks (in that case Response), so I can easly on demand build required mocks, e.g. Response with status code 200 and some custom entity attached.

Comment: this really should be the answer

Comment: If you use this approach and IDE shows warning `Unchecked assignment java.lang.Class to java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>`, try using this: `doReturn("some_str").when(response).readEntity((Class<?>)any(Class.class))`

Answer (score 4):

I hit this problem myself, trying to mock a client to a remote service by using `Response.ok(entity).build()` and then allow my client code to do `response.readEntity(...)` on the response from my faked up server.

I discuss the subject in https://codingcraftsman.wordpress.com/2018/11/26/testing-and-mocking-jersey-responses/

The issue is that the `Response.build()` method is intended to produce an *outbound* response, which is meant to be serialized before being received and deserialized by a real client. The `readEntity` method is expecting to be called at the point of deserialization.

As other posters have observed, `readEntity` on an outbound `Response` will give you the exact entity object you put in. You can even cast it to whatever type you want. Of course this doesn't work on a real inbound response, since the inbound response just has the text/binary of the inbound stream from the server.

I wrote the following code to allow me to use mockito to force an outbound `Response` to pretend to be an inbound one:

```
  /**
   * Turn a locally made {@link Response} into one which can be used as though inbound.
   * This enables readEntity to be used on what should be an outbound response
   * outbound responses don't support readEntity, but we can fudge it using
   * mockito.
   * @param asOutbound response built as though being sent to the received
   * @return a spy on the response which adds reading as though inbound
   */
  public static Response simulateInbound(Response asOutbound) {

    Response toReturn = spy(asOutbound);
    doAnswer(answer((Class<?> type) -> readEntity(toReturn, type)))
        .when(toReturn)
        .readEntity(ArgumentMatchers.<Class<?>>any());
    return toReturn;
  }

  // use the getEntity from the real object as
  // the readEntity of the mock
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static <T> T readEntity(Response realResponse, Class<T> t) {
    return (T)realResponse.getEntity();
  }
```

Comment: Where is that readEntity(toReturn, type) method coming from? Using asOutbound.getEntity() instead works for me, but I was curious as to why I could not get your method to work as is.

Comment: Sorry for those who found this a bit of a dead end - I'd forgotten to supply the `readEntity` function. I've updated the post to show it.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `readEntity(OutputClass.class)` you can do something like:

```
OutputClass entity = (OutputClass)outboundJaxrsResponse.entity
```

Comment: Not ideal to have to change source, but this did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of these answers worked because I was trying to write a server-side unit test that tested the body of the generated `Response` instance, itself. I got this exception by calling a line like `String entity = readEntity(String.class)`. Instead of mocking `Response` object, I wanted to test it.

The fix for me was to substitute the above problematic line to one like:

```
String entity = (String) outboundJaxrsResponse.getEntity();
```

Comment: Or also ```LinkedHashMap result = (LinkedHashMap)successResponse.getEntity();``` ..

Comment: Thanks, this was more helpful than the accepted response!

Answer (score 1):

I solved mocking the responses:

```
@Spy Response response;

...

// for assignments in code under testing:
doReturn( response ).when( dwConnector ).getResource( anyString() );

// for entity and response status reading:
doReturn( "{a:1}".getBytes() ).when( response ).readEntity( byte[].class );
doReturn( 200 ).when( response ).getStatus();
```

These can help if your steer is to manually create a ScopedJaxrsResponse instead:

- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/jersey-client-testing-external-calls.html
- http://www.smipple.net/snippet/somatik/Jersey%20REST%20client%20mocking

Answer (score 0):

Test code:

```
ClientResponse<?> response = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<String>>() {});
```

Mocking:

```
doReturn("test").when(response).getEntity(any(GenericType.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mock the OutboundJaxrsResponse#readEntity() method with whatever you need to return. e.g (using JMockit):

```
new MockUp<OutboundJaxrsResponse>(){
        @Mock
        public String readEntity(Class<String> clazz){ return jsonValue;}
    };
```