# Mockito mocking a Response class

Tags: java, jax-rs, mockito

When I try to mock a javax.ws.rs.core `Response` I get a error message:

> Unable to create a JAX-RS runtime Delegate

Why does this happen?

```
 Response response = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
```

But when I try to mock a HttpServletResponse there is no issue with that!

```
 HttpServletResponse response1 = Mockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4317631/4796021

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera still the same issue!

Comment: As far as I know, HttpServletResponse is an Interface, Response is an abstract class.

Comment: Which version of Mockito are you using? I am using 1.9.5 and that works. Can you show some more code of the test?

Answer (score 4):

You can try with a fake response like this:

```
ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok();
when(client.form(any(Form.class))).thenReturn(responseBuilder.entity("his is a string").build();
```

In this snippet "when" is a mockito method, and responseBuilder object return a simple string.

Comment: This won't support being read by a client, as `Response.ok` is for an outbound response, when most likely you need an `Inbound` one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844646/mock-or-build-a-jersey-inboundjaxrsresponse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086621/read-response-body-in-jax-rs-client-from-a-post-request/38797942

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557672/unable-to-mock-glassfish-jersey-client-response-object