# How to Parse javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dom, jax-rs

I am having trouble understanding how to parse javax.ws.rs.core.Response. Some people have pointed to using an InputStream, but I am not understanding how that works since the return type of response.getEntity() is of type Object. For example:

```
Response response = client.target(enpoint).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get();
InputStream is = response.getEntity();
```

NetBeans complains and says I will need to cast type Object to InputStream. The response is going to consist of XML and I just want to be able to parse it with DOM. I am having trouble getting from javax.ws.rs.core.Response to anything useful.

Any ideas?

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086621/read-response-body-in-jax-rs-client-from-a-post-request

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For JAX-RS 2.x Client API, use [`Response.readEntity(InputStream.class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity%28java.lang.Class%29). Alternatively, is you don't need any specific information from the `Response` object, you can simple do

```
InputStream is = client.target(enpoint).request(
                            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(InputStream.class);
```

Comment: Ah. That's what I was trying to accomplish (.readEntity(InputStream.class) and it makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: It actually doesn't make perfect sense. It is a terrible API design to overload a method that would normal convert the content to the given type with one that returns the input stream for the content instead. But... thank you for this, it is hopefully what I need!

Answer (score 3):

Also works:

```
MyResponse myResponse = response.readEntity(MyResponse.class);
```

Answer (score -2):

InputStream responseBody = (InputStream) response.getEntity();